# Задать количество столбцов в matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Как указать количество столбцов в гистограмме?
при построении получается нечитаемое распределение:

[image: гистограмма]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я полагаю, вы используете `DataFrame.hist` или `Series.hist`.

Тогда для гистограммы есть параметры `bins` для числа столбцов и `width` для ширины столбцов:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['x'] = np.random.rand(1000)
n = 10
w = (max(df.x) - min(df.x))/n
df.hist('x', width = 0.85*w, bins=n)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]